# Trim down values from an string and check in the database

Tags: c#

I need to write an function in c# that trims down values from an string and should check in the database whether it is available or not .

Consider the string be `"test_test1_test2_test3"`

i have to split the values above string based on underscore. i.e initial i have to take "`test3`" from the above string and check in db whether it is available.
If not available then i have to take `test2_test3` and check in db . If not available then i have to take `test1_test2_test3` and check in db till its value is available .

Can someone help me with this ??

Sample Code :

```
string name = "test_test1_test2_test3";
int strIndex = name.LastIndexOf('_');
string value = name >= 0 ? name.Substring(strIndex + 1) : "" ; 

if(checkValue(value)){


}else{

    // Now i have to repeat the above process and take the next part of string and check for its availablity in db .
    // i.e for test2_test3

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Split` the string and loop through `array` and append values in string which you want to match to database.

```
string name = "test_test1_test2_test3";
string[] arr = name.Split('_');
string strToMatch = string.Empty;

for (int i = arr.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
{

   if (i != arr.Length - 1)
       strToMatch = arr[i] + "_" + strToMatch;
   else
       strToMatch = arr[i];

}
```

Comment: Works.If the strToMatch  available in db how can i cut the text before and after and store it an separate string .
i.e Lets consider the test2_test3 is available in db.
Now i have to store test_test1 in a string and test2_test3 in another string ? 
How can i acheive this ?

Comment: When a string is available in DB you can get substring from original string and store in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-build [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method of string class. This method is split the string based upon a specific character (in your case it is underscore "_") and make a string array. Further you can iterate this string array and implement your logic there.

**For E.g.**

```
string name = "test_test1_test2_test3";
var stringArray = name.Split('_');

foreach (var item in stringArray)
{
   //Call to DB, for checking string exists or not

   If (StringExists)
   {
      break;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my answer this way it is nicely divided into several functions

```
    private void functionX()
    {
        string name = "test_test1_test2_test3";
        string[] splitValues = name.Split('_');

        bool notIndDB = false;
        int startIndex = splitValues.Length;

        while (!notIndDB && startIndex >= 0)
        {
            notIndDB = Check(BuildString(startIndex--, splitValues));                
        }
    }

    private string BuildString(int startIndex, string[] splitValues)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = startIndex; i <= splitValues.Length -1; i++)
        {
            builder.Append((i != splitValues.Length -1 ? splitValues[i] + "_" : splitValues[i]));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private bool Check(string parameter)
    {
        bool isFound = false;
        //Check if string is in db

        return isFound;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `list` of all possible variations by next:

```
var str = "test_test1_test2_test3";
var arr = str.Split('_').ToList();
var list = new List<string> { str };
while (arr.Count > 1)
{
     arr.RemoveAt(0);
    list.Add(string.Join("_", arr));
}
```

And i suggest to check all of them in one query.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string name = "test_test1_test2_test3";

        int pos = name.LastIndexOf("_");
        while (pos > -1)
        {
            string test_string = name.Substring(pos + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(test_string);
            pos = name.LastIndexOf("_", pos - 1);
        }
```